# Checking Equal Differences between Indices

Tags: list-manipulation

There is a matrix (4*4) `m` as below one:

```
m={{r[1,256]+r[2,257]+r[3,258]+r[4,259]+...},
   {r[309,700]+r[310,701]+r[311,702]+r[312,710]+....},......}
```

I do not write all of elements. The `r[i,j]` is created by a table and after a calculation its elements have appeared in the `m`. But in any elements of `m`, I want to see the difference between `j` and `i`. For example `256-1=255` for the first step. It must be repeated to all others which are adding to that. If for a special `r`, `j-i` is not equal to the others, I can see that `r`. I mean If I have

```
m={{r[1,256]+r[2,257]+r[3,258]+r[4,259]+...+r[10,267]},
   {r[309,700]+r[310,701]+r[311,702]+r[312,710]+....},......}
```

I must be notified that `r[10,267]` is wrong. Because it must be `r[10,265]`.

Since There are many elements contribute to `m` I am not able to do that by hand. How can I gain this goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's make some fake data to play with:

```
data = Table[r[n + m, 255 + n + m], {n, 1, 20}, {m, {0, 10}}];
```

Then let's introduce an error:

```
data = data /. r[3, 258] -> r[3, 1000];
```

We can then conditionally format the `r` items that do not correspond to your rule:

```
data /. r[i_, j_] /; i + 255 != j :> Style[r[i, j], Red, Bold, Background -> Yellow]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As you can see, the offending item is visually highlighted in the output.

Comment: I am grateful to receive again one of your perfects answers as before.

Comment: @Irreversible that's very kind, you are welcome!